# Вывеси таблицу MySQL на страницу HTML

Tags: php, mysqli

Всем привет) Помогите вывести таблицу с базы данных на хтмл с помощью пхп)
Вот такая таблица должна получится   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
    <?php

define(HOST, 'localhost');
define(USER, 'root');
define(PASSWORD, '');
define(DB_NAME, 'test');

$link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_connect_error($link));

mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$query = "SELECT * FROM workers";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

mysqli_close($link);
?>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1">
<?php   
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    $mass[] = $row;
}
    foreach ($mass as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($value as $subkey =>  $subvalue) {
            echo "<td>".$subvalue."<td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
</table>
```

Вот то что у меня получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь заметны лишние ячейки(откуда они не понимаю( и заголовки столбцов пытался вывеси тегом  создав поверх такие же 2 массива, но в общем ничего хорошего с этого не поучилось)

Comment: `<td>".$subvalue."<td>"` у вас тут начинаются две ячейки и ни одна из них не закрывается (в конце должен быть `</td>` вместо второго `<td>`

Comment: @Mike ааа)) блин спасибо))) случайно упустил) перебрал миллион вариантов, как вывести таблицу и потерял тег)

Answer (score 1):

Добился желаемого результата. Но всё как-то криво) Может кто-то подскажет как упростить

```
    <?php

define(HOST, 'localhost');
define(USER, 'root');
define(PASSWORD, '');
define(DB_NAME, 'test');

$link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_connect_error($link));

mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$query = "SELECT * FROM workers";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

mysqli_close($link);
?>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1">
<?php   
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {       //Законектились к базе и записываем значения
    $mass[] = $row;                                 // рядков в массив
}

foreach ($mass as $key =>  $value) {                //Все преведенные здесь маннипуляции
    foreach ($value as $skey => $svalue) {          //связаны с заголовками столбцов таблицы оесть с ее ключами.
        $arr[] = $skey;                             //              
        $arr = array_unique($arr);                  // В forech, я ложу все ключи в массив и удаляю дубликаты,
    }                                               // чтобы у меня осались только 4 значения вместо 16.
}                                                   //
echo "<tr>";                                        //Здесь просто вывожу полученый массив ключей.
for ($i=0; $i < count($arr) ; $i++) {               //
    echo "<th>".$arr[$i]."</th>";                   //PS: всё как-то громоздко и криво)) Должен быть 
}                                                   //способ все это улучшить! 
echo "</tr>";                                       //

foreach ($mass as $key => $value) {                 //
    echo "<tr>";                                    // Отрисовуем таблицу значений      
    foreach ($value as $subkey =>  $subvalue) {     //  
        echo "<td>".$subvalue."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1">
<tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($result as $key => $value) {?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <?php echo $value['id'] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $value['name'] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $value['age'] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $value['salary'] ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]